# Netbeans - Apache Derby: How to export to XML?

Tags: database, netbeans, jdbc, export

I have an Apache Derby database built in Netbeans.  I'm wondering if there is anyway to export the table contents as xml.

for example:

```
`<employee>
<name="Kal"/>
<ID=10/>
<employee/>`   where employee is table name, name and ID just attributes
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several (free) options

- 'print' the data to a file in xml format (bad idea)
- use [JAXB](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/index-140168.html)
- use [XMLStreamWriter](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/JDK-6/XMLStreamWriterDemo.htm)

All of these involve writing some Java code. Unfortunately, there is no built in functionality in Derby for XML export. It only supports a [CSV format](http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.4/tools/ctoolsimportdefaultformat.html).  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you can do XML this way, but perhaps this will provide an intermediate step:

http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.4/tools/ctoolsimport16245.html

It's a guide written by Apache on how to import and export data from a Derby db.

Comment: thanks for quick replying, I went through that document, but I got confused--> how can I write that procedures to export data by using netbeans, I don't know if you have any idea and thanks once again

Comment: For sure!  By using Netbeans, do do you mean exporting the data by using Netbeans itself?  The documentation is pretty light on the subject: http://wiki.netbeans.org/IEC.DataManagement.Main#1._Database_Import.2FExport_Feature  (it appears the feature was considered for Netbeans 7?).   You may have better luck contacting the Netbeans people directly.